# Kinect says it's not on a horizontal surface. is it broken?

Tags: xbox-360, kinect

my kinect (on xbox 360) keeps saying that it's not on a horizontal surface, and it refuses to work.
It's on a perfectly horizontal surface.
it has a fixed red light and the sensor does not move.

I think it's broken but I'm not sure.
what could I do about it?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From [xbox support:](http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-360/kinect/kinect-not-level)

This means one of three things:

- The kinect is not level (obviously not the case)
- The kinect is at a temperature extreme (in which case, let it cool to room temperature)
- The sensor is broken and needs replacing/repairing

Comment: ok, thank you @imulsion,
I'm in point 3. I would like to trace down the cause of the problem and try to fix it... where should I start?

Comment: @user160057 My first thought would be googling the problem, and then if that doesn't work I would take it back to the shop or contact xbox support. It's not usually a good idea to try and fix it yourself unless you know exactly what you're doing.